# How to start an application with bottom most property?

Tags: window-management

I want to start an application with bottom-most property. That means that the window will remain always in the bottom of the other windows.

Is this possible? I think that there must be an application that does such a thing, but I have not idea how to find it...

For example, I want to start `chromium-browser` with bottom most property. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *Devilspie2* (http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/), a program which performs actions on windows as they are created, using scripts written in *Lua* (http://www.lua.org/manual/)

Install it with: `sudo apt-get install devilspie2`, then run `devilspie2`.  You should see the error message:

```
No script files found in the script folder - exiting.
```

It will have created this folder as `~/.config/devilspie2/`.  Create the following file, and save it in this directory with the extension `.lua`, e.g. as `chromium.lua`:

```
debug_print("Window Name: " .. get_window_name())
debug_print("Application name: " .. get_application_name())
debug_print("WM_CLASS: " .. get_class_instance_name())
debug_print("Window Class: " .. get_window_class())
if (string.match(get_application_name(),"Chromium$")) then
   set_window_below();
end
```

Then run `devilspie2 --debug &` and open *Chromium*.  The terminal should show:

```
Window Name: Untitled - Chromium
Application name: Untitled - Chromium
```

All *Chromium* windows (any application name ending in 'Chromium') opened while *Devilspie2* is running will now be set to be below all normal windows.

Opening other programs while *Devilspie2* is running with the debug switch, should help you modify this code for other applications.

### To automatically run *Devilspie2*

Create a file `~/.config/autostart/devilspie2.desktop`, containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Devilspie2
Exec=devilspie2
NoDisplay=true
Terminal=false
```

### Adding Additional Conditions

To run a script for an application only sometimes, you could either:

- Run *Devilspie2* only as needed, e.g. `devilspie2 & app ; killall devilspie2`, though it will apply its rules to all new windows created while it is running.
- For GTK apps, the option `--name=` changes the application name, and `--class=` the Window class.  *Chromium* doesn't recognise this despite documentation.
- Run the command with a modified environment, e.g. `window-below= chromium-browser`, and instead use the following rule:

  ```
  if (string.match(get_application_name(),"Chromium$")) and
     (string.match(io.input("/proc/" .. get_window_property("_NET_WM_PID") .. "/environ"):read("*a"), "window-below="))
  then
     set_window_below();
  end
  ```

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to set the window below *only* if I start chromium using `chromium-browser --set-this-window-below` or so?

Comment: For Chromium yes.  The following works only because unrecognized options are ignored, which is unusual.  Just change`/environ` in the last example above to `/cmdline`, and `window-below=` to `--window-below`